# Button implementation in Angular Material Table

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

Hi i want to import reactive form data to a angular material table and then use buttons to call pop-up windows or perform simple functions like deleting a row. My main questions is how to add buttons to a row in material table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing stops you from inserting a button component in one of your rows:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="myColumn">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> My Column </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <button mat-button>Click me!</button>
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>

</mat-table>
```

N.B. this example is taken from the *get started* page of the [table component](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview) for angular-material.

Comment: Thanks, this helps.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer helped you solve your problem, please upvote it and accept it so that other people can see it in the future. :)